# Binding the Return key not working

Tags: perl, perltk

I am trying to bind my <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on my keyboard. I am writing in Perl Tk.

I want one of the next to things to happen.

1. When I hit "Enter" on my keyboard, I want a button within my program to operate.
2. When I hit "Enter" on my keyboard, I want a subroutine to run. Either one would satisfy my program seeing that my button opens the subroutine.

Here is my relevant code:

```
# Button
my $enterbut = $find_sub->Button(
    -command => \&find_substations,
    -text => 'Find Displays',
    -background => 'gray'
)->pack(
    -side => 'left',
    -fill => 'none',
    -ipadx => 8,
    -ipady => 1
);

# Accept "Enter" key as input
$enterbut->bind('<Return>', \&find_substations);

# Output Substation ID to Pane
sub find_substations {
    print;
}
```

I have tried a few different ways of using the bind command and none of them works.

I am getting no errors but when I press the button my sub does not operate. I begin to believe <kbd>Return</kbd> may not be the correct button on my keyboard. Maybe due to driver language or something. Maybe coding error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your button. It is captured only when your button is focused. If you bind it on the whole window, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere in the window should execute the handler function.